# How to show a different node name for different user in backoffice?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have a node in backoffice.

```
<explorer-tree:navigation-node id="hmc.abc.navigation_node.businesspartner">
            <explorer-tree:type-node code="BusinessPartner" id="hmc.abc.businesspartner.treenode"/>             
</explorer-tree:navigation-node>
```

In my labels_en.properties -

```
hmc.abc.businesspartner.treenode=General title
```

Now for a particular user group say `different_user` I want to change the label to-

> Specific title

For `admin` I still want to show `General title`.

Comment: you can define different nodes shown per "principal"

Answer (score 0):

Values that we define in **labels_en.properties** file can not be dynamic. Values will be same as we define for key.

One solution will be...

1. add another key value in labels_en.properties like

   hmc.abc.businesspartner.treenode.specific=Specific title
2. Duplicate the type-node declaration in explorer tree and assign newly created key like below

   <explorer-tree:type-node code="BusinessPartner" id="hmc.abc.businesspartner.treenode.specific"/>
3. Apply restriction on type-node according to user access rights, which node to be shown for which user